# Is ever a covariance stationary process, in the real world, not mean ergodic?

Tags: time-series, stochastic-processes, stationarity, ergodic

Mean ergodicity for a *covariance stationary process* is a property that assures that the sample *time mean*  $\bar{Y}=\frac{1}{T} \sum_{t=1}^T Y_t$ converges as $T \rightarrow \infty$ to the *ensemble mean* $E[Y_t]=\lim_{N \rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N (Y_t)_n$ (ie the *sample time mean* is consistent).

For the *sample time mean* not to converge, the process needs to completely "forget" about its *ensemble average* as time passes, so at a certain point adding new observations to the *sample mean* won't add new information. This should imply that the process can't infinitely "gravitate" around its *ensemble mean*. Please correct me if I'm wrong about this.

This is clear, as an example, for a random walk process; even if the process starts at $Y_0=0$, the new value $Y_{1}$ will "reset" the *mean* for the following observed sequence of values, ie the following part of the time sample completely forgets about the starting 0. However this process is not stationary, as its variance increases with time.

Going back to *covariance stationary* processes: any process that is covariance-stationary is not necessarily mean ergodic.

Now, the process can't "gravitate" around its *ensemble mean*, but It also can't progressively wander off as a random walk does. *How would it behave?*

The examples I've seen are covariance stationary processes of this kind: $Y_t=U+ \epsilon_t$, with $\epsilon_t$ white noise. Here $E[Y_t]=E[U]$. The *sample time mean* won't converge to $E[U]$ for a given sample $\{u_i+e_1, u_i+e_2, ...\}$ as it will converge to the single realization of $U$ for that given sample ($u_i$).

So the behavior of this kind of processes is summed up as: the process gravitates around some value which however is not the *ensemble mean* of the process. **Are there any covariance stationary, non mean ergodic processes that don't exhibit this kind behaviour?** The sample time mean *has to* converge to something for each time sample, given the variance of the process is finite, **right?** (it just can't converge to the ensemble mean)

Now to the final question: *assuming* we will ever get to experience only *one* realization (path) of a process (so excluding situations where you can look at multiple paths), then $U$ "doesn't exist by our point of view". Our reality is $u_i$, and the process will be ergodic for estimating $u_i$, so we wouldn't know the process is not truly ergodic (by looking at multiple paths), and we wouldn't care anyway (since we are trying to model and predict the future of our realization, our reality, we don't care about $E[U]$). *In this situation*, a process not truly mean ergodic wouldn't be a real problem.

**Now, a covariance stationary process, of which we can't even consistently estimate a constant value (like $u_i$) as the mean of the single path which is our perspective, would be a problem.
Does a covariance stationary process like this exist?**

(this is what happens with a random walk, but the process is not covariance stationary)

Comment: Non-ergodicity / spontaneous-symmetry-breaking is rather well established and commonplace in physics and nature see, e.g., [this famous article](https://www.tkm.kit.edu/downloads/TKM1_2011_more_is_different_PWA.pdf)

Comment: Wouldn't almost any [stopped process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stopped_process) (of which there are a great many "real world" examples in finance, *e.g.*) qualify as an example?

Comment: @whuber yeah, I guess it would, I didn't think about that. However for a stopped process the time mean still converges to a constant value. Now I'm thinking about a process $Y_t=\epsilon_k$ for $2^k>t>=2^{k-1}$, with $k=1,2,...$. Here the time mean wouldn't ever converge to anything I think. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, the time mean converges to a constant: but it's usually not the same as the common mean of the process.

Comment: @whuber Yes, that's true. Now that I think about it however, my example is surely not covariance stationary. I don't know how I feel about a stopped process, wouldn't the auto-covariance increase as time increases, because the probability of the process being stopped increases with time? If it was the case, then the stopped process example wouldn't apply here

Comment: Let's not confuse properties of individual paths with those of the process!  A nice model to bear in mind is a process of the form $X_t = X$ for a fixed random variable $X$ (with finite second moment). This is second order stationary, but every path is constant. Arguably, this is a "real world model" in which anything in the world that we view as persistent over time is viewed as a constant-valued temporal process. Now add to this, say, a white noise process (for measurement error) and you obtain a nontrivial example of the kind of process you are looking for: stationary but not ergodic.

Comment: @whuber true, but isn't this the same kind of example ($Y_t=U+\epsilon_t$) I provided in the original question? My point is, even if these kind of processes are truly not ergodic, from our perspective they are (or seem) ergodic. We will only look at a *single* path which has it's own "mean" that we can estimate consistently. If *mean non-ergodicity* only was like this why would it be a problem? Now, a covariance stationary process, of which we can't even estimate a constant value of our single path (as happens with random walks), would be a real problem. These are the examples I'm looking for.

Comment: It's not the case that we always look at a single path.  For instance, some spatio-temporal models posit comparable time series processes at different points and we may have observations of many of them.  And it is still worth pointing out that maybe what you originally *thought* was not a "real world" model really might be--that is the version of your question I have been responding to, not the stuff that led up to it.

Comment: @whuber you are right, "real world" processes was a terrible way of describing what I was looking for, my bad. Should I edit the question? Moreover, the possibility of looking at multiple paths is another aspect I didn't think about. However, do you think an example of what (now in a clearer way) I'm looking for could exist? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Since, IMHO, the existing answer doesn't really address your question--it reads more like an extended comment--I think it would be OK to edit it for clarification.

Comment: @whuber I've edited the question, thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

As you point out, at least for "real" processes which happen over historical time, there is no way we can tell whether they look ergodic or not: a single realization is all we get to see.

I think is was A.J. Ayer who said that, for a question to be meaningful, we should be able to describe an experiment whose outcome would provide an answer. Inasmuch as we cannot experiment reversing time, we probably cannot answer your question for time processes.

I conjecture that we could obtain empirical results close to ergodicity for processes not indexed over time. For instance, if we could measure a magnitude (e.g., temperature) along infinite paths in different directions starting from planet Earth, it is conceivable that the averages measured along each "ray" might be close to the ensemble average. But this is mere speculation.